# How to to set the calendar start date and end date in java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

Is there any way to set the calendar start date and end date in  java.util.Calendar.
Like say for example, by default, the starting date of  java.util.Calendar is 01 January and calendar end date is 31st December. I have some specific case, in which I want the calendar to get start from 5th January and end on 28th December.

Even if this is possible using some other date-time library in java, then it would be of use for me.
Any idea/suggestion how to set this starting date and ending date for a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

As the doc says, the java.util.Calendar class is used for converting a specific moment in time, not representing a span of time. Indeed, the old date-time classes bundled with Java such as java.util.Date and .Calendar lack any representations of a span of time.

Also, those classes are notoriously troublesome and confusing, flawed both in design and implementation. Avoid them. Use either Joda-Time or the new java.time package built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

Joda-Time offers various ways to define a span of time: Interval, Period, and Duration.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime start = new DateTime( 2014, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, timeZone );
DateTime stop = new DateTime( 2014, 12, 28, 0 , 0, 0, timeZone );
Interval interval = new Interval( start, stop );
boolean containsNow = interval.contains( DateTime.now() );
```